# Starting Activity from Fragment causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm stuck here with a problem starting an activity from a Button inside a Fragment.
Here is my code:

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

}
```

**ViewPagerActivity.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import com.package.here.Class1Overview;
import com.package.here.Class1Overview;
import com.package.here.Class1Overview;

public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.my_viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(initialisePaging());
    }

    private ViewPagerAdapter initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Class1Overview.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Class2Overview.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Class3Overview.class.getName()));
        return new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);          
    }

}
```

**Class1Overview.java** (Here is the button)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.package.here.R;

public class FuelOverview extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_one_layout, container, false);
        View AddBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        ((Button) AddBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getActivity(), ActivityToStart.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

And this is my **LogCat**:

```
01-05 19:39:00.913: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.package.here/com.package.here.ViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1022)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1180)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3144)
01-05 19:39:01.034: E/AndroidRuntime(10557):    ... 12 more
01-05 19:39:01.423: I/dalvikvm(10557): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
```

ViewPager itself is working fine. It seems to be an error pausing the FragmentActivity, but i can't figure it out. The only thing I found was this post on google http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917

I also got through the google example code to make sure I mainly use the same technique...

Edit: to make sure the ClickListener works, I tried a Toast in the onClick method - works perfectly.

Comment: Just figured out the following:

FragmentActivity crashes when:
- pressing home button
- turning the orientation of the device
- starting an Avtivity
- calling finish works fine

So for the moment this works for me:

Overwrite the onSaveInstanceState method without calling the super method and you're fine. Except for the fact, that the instance state isn't saved :D So this is not really a fix, but may nail down the problem.

Comment: I just had the same problem - the issue for me was caused when I added a new fragment to my project with an empty layout. It seems that somewhere in the code, if nothing is saved to the bundle during onSaveInstanceState it must cause a null pointer exception. Adding some views to my layouts fixed the issue (after hours spent bashing my head against a wall). I am using android support library v4 revision 10.

Comment: @Juke Is it possible to get same behaviour of TabViewActivity using fragmentation, I want to open a new activity in fragmentation area on selectyion od any tab?

Comment: @Juke I am able to draw a new Fragment (not activity) on click of button in fragment view, but if I open same fragment again, it's calling Fragment.onCreateView calling everytime...I do not want to load view everytime..any idea/suggestion.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a known problem and I'm shocked to find that no one has filed a bug on the public bug tracker for this.

Your problem stems from this:

```
if (f.mSavedViewState != null) {
    if (result == null) {
        result = new Bundle();
    }
    result.putSparseParcelableArray(
            FragmentManagerImpl.VIEW_STATE_TAG, f.mSavedViewState);
}
if (!f.mUserVisibleHint) {
    // Only add this if it's not the default value
    result.putBoolean(FragmentManagerImpl.USER_VISIBLE_HINT_TAG, f.mUserVisibleHint);
}
```

You should notice that if `result` is `null` coming into this code and the first `if` is not triggered you'll get a `NullPointerException` if we enter the second `if`.

It should read:

```
if (f.mSavedViewState != null) {
    if (result == null) {
        result = new Bundle();
    }
    result.putSparseParcelableArray(
            FragmentManagerImpl.VIEW_STATE_TAG, f.mSavedViewState);
}
if (!f.mUserVisibleHint) {
    if (result == null) {
        result = new Bundle();
    }
    // Only add this if it's not the default value
    result.putBoolean(FragmentManagerImpl.USER_VISIBLE_HINT_TAG, f.mUserVisibleHint);
}
```

I submitted a patch for this a week or two ago: https://android-review.googlesource.com/31261

Comment: What will be solution of this issue? Should I use another lib? I have same problem.

Comment: Patch the bug, recompile the support library yourself until the next version comes out. Its sources are in `SDK/extras/android/support/v4/src/`.

Comment: Can you post steps to recompile this?

Comment: @PankajKumar it's pretty simple, just create a new Java project on Eclipse using the source of the `SDK/extras/android/support/v4/src/`, add the SDK library for API 14 `SDK/platforms/android-14/android.jar` in the project libraries and export it as a JAR file. Done! :)

Comment: @Petter Hello, I have followed the instructions found here->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636201/how-to-create-a-project-from-existing-source-in-eclipse-and-then-find-it (I remembered eclipse had an option for creating project from existing source... maybe I am wrong) Any way I have followed the steps found in the above link and Petter suggestions. I have changed the jar in my project and used the newly generated one but now when a FragmentActivity is started a  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is thrown, have anyone got that issue?

Comment: @maxsap ,@Pankaj Kumar u have got any solution ? I have same issue

Comment: I've applied the changes Jake outlined above and compiled a new support library to use until Google releases his fix. http://ara.sh/android/android-support-v4.jar

Comment: @JakeWharton I just ran into this today. The most recent version of the support lib fixes the issue.

Comment: @ArashPayan Very Much Thank You guy, I got stucked without this jar  now I resolved my issue with that jar, You have done a great job for me. thanks!

Comment: Will it help if I use [android-support-v13.jar] instead of [android-support-v4.jar] ?

Answer (score 62):

Quick fix is

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        setUserVisibleHint(true);
    }
```

And wait for update in safe mode :)

Comment: btw, issue was fixed by last March-2012 update of SupportPackage

Comment: I was still having this issue as of 23/4/2012 .. but this answer fixed it nicely

Comment: Weird, I don't use own fix myself more :)

Comment: Oooops. This fix remains actual in few cases! I returned and continue to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the fix... had this come up when using ABS + ViewPagerIndicator... this did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @BryanDenny OMG, this fix the annoying ABS's FragmentTabPager example too! Just need to place this in all the SherlockFragment declared :)

Comment: I was facing the same issue. worked perfectly. Had to put this piece of code in all the fragments. thanks :)

Comment: i am not able to got it. what is this setUserVisibleHint(true); I am getting same error, please help me.

Answer (score 32):

According to a post [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19211#c13), you should be using FragmentStatePagerAdapter rather than FragmentPagerAdapter.  I had the same problem you described, and making that switch worked for me.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me as well

Comment: Same here. Any idea why is this?

Comment: Having this problem, even if using FragmentStatePagerAdapter (using v13 support lib)

Comment: I had similar problem using v13 support lib. I was using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and it was fine until I tried to add third page. Adding another page crashed the app with NPE above in the question. Ironically, the solution was to **switch back to FragmentPagerAdapter**.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem - the issue for me was caused when I added a new fragment to my project with an empty layout. It seems that if nothing is saved to the bundle during `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` it causes a null pointer exception in `FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState`.

Adding some views to my layouts fixed the issue (after hours spent bashing my head against a wall). Using android support library v4 revision 10.

Also when using a `ListView` as the root for the fragment layout, if the listview has no elements you will also get the crash. In the fragment class, override `onSaveInstanceState` like this to put some data in the bundle:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("DO NOT CRASH", "OK");
}
```

Comment: Both your and Vadim's solutions worked for me.  I am using support v13 FragmentStatePageAdapter. Yours is more fun though.