# No fragment showing on ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My ViewPager does not show any fragments even though it load the fragment for my "Review section". I used the same code with my "rating section" and it work, even tried redo the ViewPager and adapter but still no progress. By the way i'm doing this within a fragment.

I put a log in the adapter to show whether the fragment is working and also change my Viewpager's background color to check if it's visible or not. Even though the ViewPager is visible but the fragment still does not show.

UPDATE: I found out that the problem caused by the activity i use to replace with the fragments.

Here the code snippet (in my activity which hold both "Rating Section" and "review Section".

```
SubSectionFragment_Rating subSectionFragment_rating = new SubSectionFragment_Rating();
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ratingSection,subSectionFragment_rating, subSectionFragment_rating.getTag()).commit();

    SubSectionFragment_ReviewAndInstructions subSectionFragment = new SubSectionFragment_ReviewAndInstructions();
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.subTab,subSectionFragment, subSectionFragment.getTag()).commit();
```

[ViewPager is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nomzo.jpg)

[Should display this fragment in ViewPager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK8An.jpg)

Review.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hybridelements.openchef.fragment_activities.fragment_subs.SubSectionFragment_ReviewAndInstructions">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Review.java (part of the code)

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions adapter = new SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions.java

```
public SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs){
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            ReviewsFragment subTab1 = new ReviewsFragment();
            Log.d("ReviewAndInstruction","ReviewsFragment loaded");
            return subTab1;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you returned rootview in OnCreateView method of fragment.

Comment: i've checked to make sure every OnCreateView method return rootView. Still no fix

Comment: Try with `getChildFragmentManager()` like this: `final SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions adapter = new SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());`

Comment: When using getChildFragmentManager() . get this error **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.SparseArray.get(int)' on a null object reference**

Comment: That is the issue with somewhere else in code. Update the question with logcat and code where exception is thrown.

Comment: May be try to remove tools:context="com.hybridelements.openchef.fragment_activities.fragment_subs.SubSectionFragment_ReviewAndInstructions" from your xml file and set .Mainactivity to root element.

Comment: The problem is that it works, just that the fragment didn't want to show up, the code where the fragment generated in adapter is working, but somehow it didn't show up with no errors

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH tried it, nothing happens

Comment: update OnCreateView method of ReviewFragments.Java class in Ques.

Comment: what kind of update you ask for in ReviewFragments.Java? because there's nothing inside it, i expect the layout will appear in ViewPager as it did on my 'Rating Section"

Comment: @Yupi The thing is, there are no any exception thrown, that's what caught me off guard.

Comment: If you are using nested fragments in this case you have to provide `getChildFragmentManager();` to your pager adaper and your min SDK need to be at least 17. For below SDKs you need to use different approach. After this if you get an exception then you have more errors in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to @Yupi for the suggestion to change from `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragment()`. during the problem occurred, when change to `getChildFragment()` got an error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.SparseArray.get(int)' on a null object reference

To fix this error, i need to change my activity that start the fragment transaction, so here's the solution to the problem for nested fragments.

ViewItem.Java (**BEFORE**)

```
FragmentManager manager;

manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

ViewItem.Java (**AFTER**)

```
FragmentTransaction manager;

manager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

SubPagerFragment_ReviewAndInstructions.java (**BEFORE**)

```
final SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions adapter = new SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

SubPagerFragment_ReviewAndInstructions.java (**AFTER**)

```
final SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions adapter = new SubPagerAdapter_ReviewAndInstructions(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
```

**Result**

[Fragment correctly displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm4yf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `childFragmentManager` and `addToBackStack` still not fixed my issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655874/3763032) solution might work instead. With combination from @burning-violet solution.

1. `childFragmentManager` used to construct the ViewPager
2. Using `FragmentStatePageAdapter`
3. `override restoreState()`
4. Without using `addToBackStack(null)` // this optional, if you don't want to add to backstack

The `restoreState()` try catch will only silence the error (NPE), it must be fixed accordingly.