# Crash when adding Firebase for Google Ads in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to add in an older project google ads banner, but when I add to the Grandle the Firebase and run the app it crashes:

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com...."
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile files('libs/pinch-0.8.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-async-3.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-examples-3.0.3.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the error message
[image]

The first version of the project was developed with Eclipse.

Comment: How do you implement your ads inside both code and xml?

Comment: I did not implement them. It crashes just when I import the firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because firebase uses new version of android support lib while actionbarsherlock relies on old version.  If you still want to use actionbarsherlock you will need to make some changes into it, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604423/6095439)

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to add main firebase project :

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'`

Comment: I added but the same error occurs. Also according to google docs does not seem to be a problem if you do not add the main firebase project https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start.

Comment: @GeorgeVardikos , ok .read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16498014/1979882

Comment: good resource but applications Activities extends SherlockFragment