# How to build the Android support package

Tags: android, android-support-library

In this [question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748064/starting-activity-from-fragment-causes-nullpointerexception) the only fix involves rebuilding the Android support library from it's source. I'm not sure how to do this. In Eclipse, I've tried: File -> Import -> General -> File System -> with path-to-SDK/extras/android/support/v4/src/. This imported all of the files. Then I added android.jar for version 14 to the build path. This still gave me a ton of errors, and I'm not sure how to export a jar with the fixed source. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add every folder inside extras/android/compatibility/v4/src as independent source folder to get sources in project properly.

Comment: A java project or an android project?

Comment: It's a .jar library, a Java project

Comment: No you cannot create a Java project with it. It contains lots of Android dependencies.

Comment: Of course you can, despite Android dependencies, you are going to build a jar library, not an Android app, and those Android dependencies are jar libraries too, so they can be included as usual