# How recompile the support lib of android v4?

Tags: android

I encountered a similar problem, [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748064/starting-activity-from-fragment-causes-nullpointerexception)

the best answer want to me recompile the support library ,How to do it

Comment: One of the comments at that answer explains how it's done. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes, i tried, I create a new Java project on Eclipse using the source of the SDK/extras/android/support/v4/src/. But it has many errors, it seems can't recompile(may be I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

import each of the folders inside src separately.

courtesy of djpeinado:
[How to build the Android support package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526769/how-to-build-the-android-support-package)