# Starting ACTION_VIEW Activity from SherlockFragment causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

I'm using sherlockFragment.
When I press button call on that fragment to start a call activity using Intent, It caused an error but the web still load.   when I close call activity, the error appear again.
I've tried replace latest android.support.v4.jar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748064/starting-activity-from-fragment-causes-nullpointerexception) but the error still the same.
I've tried start call activity on this way:

```
public class PlaceDetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
        //blabla
       public void browseWebPage(final String url){
            getSherlockActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(websiteUrl)));
        }
}
```

And this way

```
public class PlaceDetailsFragment extends SherlockFragment {
        //blabla
    public void browseWebPage(final String url){
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(websiteUrl));
         startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

but still got same error
Logcat

```
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:127)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1137)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1215)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:2951)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3010)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1222)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-20 11:37:28.971: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the problem occured to ACTION_VIEW and ACTION_CALL either
any solution to help me out ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748064/starting-activity-from-fragment-causes-nullpointerexception

Comment: @Rstar Thanks for reply but I've tried that. Still get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution for this problem. It caused by using sherlockFragment with ViewIndicator or other stuff.
to fix the problem, just Override the menthod of all fragment to:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);
}
```

solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446326/2212742)

Comment: hey... i experienced the same thing when I have SherlockFragmentActivity. But that code above you put isn't solving anything.