# Importing Open Source Projects

Tags: eclipse, open-source

I downloaded [hedgewars](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/source/checkout) and proceeded to import the file to Eclipse.  I went to File>Import || General>Existing Project from Workspace || and I set the root directory where the hedgewars folder was downloaded.  It then gives me an error saying " No projects are found to import".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An 'Existing Project' means that there must be a `.project` file in the root directory. If there's not, then it's best to just import from the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: [How to create a project from existing source in Eclipse and then find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636201/how-to-create-a-project-from-existing-source-in-eclipse-and-then-find-it)
You may need to create a new project with existing sources if the project that you download don't have a project of eclipse inside

Answer (score -1):

If there is pom file, you should be able to import via Existing Maven Projects