# how see files of project after cloning git repository with eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, project

i recovered a project from git depot after running "clone git repository command" in

i can see branches in Eclipse git explorer.

but now how to start with opening files from this project ?

I tried 'import project ' in git explorer and in package explorer but it return an error

" could not import project located at : c:\users..."

I surely miss a step ..

thanks for help

Comment: Q: Does the Git repository you cloned happen to contain an Eclipse project (e.g. ".project" directory and project configuration files)?  If not, then you must (re)create the Eclipse project manually.

Comment: it's code i recover , i assume it was an eclipse project, but previous developer is no longer here.. is there a way to check this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: I assume it was an eclipse project... is there a way to check this?

A: An Eclipse project will typically have a `.project` and a `.classpath` file (both Eclipse-generated) at the root.

The part David M. Karr is alluding to is that, if you have a "project", you probably still need to "import" it into a "workspace".  I'm worried that maybe you don't even have a "Eclipse" project - just some Java source code (and perhaps a "pom.xml" or similar "build file").

SUGGESTIONS:

1. You absolutely need at least a basic familiarity with Eclipse before you can hope to successfully build anything.  Here is a good overview:

   - [Vogel: Using the Eclipse IDE for Java programming - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html)
2. It doesn't matter how you clone the Git repository: you can do it manually (from Git), or you can use Eclipse's Git plugin.
3. See if the project you checked out has a `.project` file.  If it doesn't, you'll probably need to create one from scratch.  It isn't difficult.  See the [Vogella](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html) tutorial, or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9280568/421195).
4. If you have a ".project" file - but still aren't able to "build" - then "import", per David M. Karr's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Cloning a git repository just creates a local git repository. You will have to import the directory in that repository as an Eclipse project.  You'll have to focus on the error you get doing that.

Comment: Of course, it's also possible the OP never actually checked the Eclipse project files in to Git: only the project source :(