# eclipse "problems during content assist" popup

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

While typing some Java code, I hit the dot/member operator (`.`) as in the dot inside `ObjectName.methodName` and got this error in a popup in Eclipse:

```
The `org.elcipse.jst.ws.jaxws.ui.jaxwsjavacompletioncomputer` 
proposal computer from the `org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.ui` 
plug-in did not complete normally.
```

A second popup immediately followed with the message:

```
"Cannot perform operation: The compilation unit 
is not in the build path of a Java project".
```

Does this mean some required library is not installed as it needs to be?

Comment: you can resolve your broblem here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727305/3237665

Comment: I have the same problem. Kindly help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50897913/how-do-i-fix-this-content-assist-errors-in-java-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment88795473_50897913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [some of the occurrences](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-cvs-dev/msg00440.html) [out there](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=81558), it looks like your current project has no "Java nature" attached to it.

Check the project properties. See [if its `.project` file has a `javanature` in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179439/how-to-change-an-eclipse-default-project-to-a-java-project).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Eclipse installation is a bit confused.  In my experience the best approach here is to discard your current installation, and unpack a new.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your .project contains `javanature` as follows :

```
<natures>
<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

If it is missing, add it...

It's very late, but I hope someone will find it useful.