# Eclipse warning: "problems during content assist"

Tags: eclipse

Every time I start Eclipse and press *`Ctrl + Space`* I get the following 3 warning popups.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUsy7.jpg

They are only appearing the first time I press *`Ctrl + Space`*.
I get these warnings since i reinstalled the jdk.

I already tried to re-install eclipse, but as soon as I import my old projects the warnings seems to reappear. I currently have the following java versions installed:

```
JVE 7_u7 32bit;  
JVE 7_u7 64bit;  
JDK 7_u7 64bit;  
JDK 7_u7 32bit.
```

I added all of them in the PATH variable in the same order as listed above.
I also have eclipse set to use the `JDK 7_u7 64bit` (btw I'm using eclipse 64bit).

I hope somebody knows a solution for my problem and excuse me for my bad english, I am not an native English speaker. ;)

Comment: I am using Eclipse for Java Devs (Juno).

Comment: You might have more luck making a ticket on Eclipse's bug tracker for this (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/), since it appears to be a bug rather than something you're doing wrong.

Comment: Check the Error Log view for the underlying exception, that would give you a clue as to which plug-in caused the problem. You can also use that to report a bug.

Comment: I created an bug report over at bug.eclipse.org/bugs and uploaded the error log ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can resolve this issue by turning off Subwords-Completion in:
Window > Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions: ==> incheck(Subwords-Completion)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I got the similar type of warning is eclipse spring tool suite(sts) .I unchecked CodeRecommendors Proposals(addons) which is present 2 times in the above list and below list and it worked.To do it go to window-->preferences-->java-->editor-->Content Assist-->advanced.see the screenshot.[image]

Comment: In my case I had to disable "Java Proposals (Code recommenders)". The problematic element should be pointed in the error prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure content assist and disable the triggers in content assist. [This link](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_editor_con_assist.htm) provides information on setting content assist preference.

[image]

Comment: This is not related to my problem. I want to use the Content Assist but everytime i use it i get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience for those who have this problem in the future. If you changed the theme of your editor recently, first change it back to the classic theme and then restart Eclipse. Then switch back to the theme(maybe dark theme) you want to use and restart Eclipse again. This is how my problem was solved.