# Content Assist Error in Spring STS

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-ide

I get the below error when I hit ctrl+space for Spring annotations autocompletion.

[image]

As soon as I hit ok button, I get the suggestions as expected.

I have tried other suggestions for disabling disabling **subwords completion processsor** and **Java Proposals(Code Recommenders**).

**Disabling the subwords**, works for me, but what if I don't want to disable this 
 feature?

**Disbaling the Java Proposals** did stop the error dialogue from appearing, but I no more get the appropriate suggestions.

For example, while looking for "@Res..." I would normally want to see Spring's RestController listed in the suggestion, but its not there.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: check this one this might help you [sts-windows-preference-java-content assist-advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871947/eclipse-warning-problems-during-content-assist)

Comment: @Deadpool been through that. As I said in my post, disabling the subwords(which is what the link that you have provided suggests) works for me. But I just wanted to know isn't there any alternate solution to this. What if I don't want to disbale the subwords feature.

Disabling one feature just to get rid of the error thrown by the other doesn't sound good.