# Convert Eclipse project type from general to Java

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm taking over another team's project and am experiencing some bizarre Eclipse issues.

I'm using Subversive as my plugin, and when I go to check the trunk out it brings me to a standard "Check Out As" dialog where it allows me to select the check out method, and the only one that works for me (or is applicable) is the last option (`Check out as a project with the name specified`).

So I specify the name, and the project then checks out as normal and all is well, except...

Although this is *supposed* to be a Java project (WARs up into a Java web app), it *seems* that the team that made the project created it as a general project (by going to `Project > Properties > Resource > Type = 'Project'`).

As such, none of the typical features that come with a Java project are enabled, including (but certainly not limited to):

- <kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't work, even if the type is defined inside the same package (folder in this case) as the type I'm currently editing (because Eclipse isn't treating this like a Java project)
- Can't search for Java classes
- Can't build from inside Eclipse (because there are not source packages, only folders), etc.
- This list goes on and on...

So my question(s) are:

- Is there a way to convert this **General Project** type into a **Java Project** without having to make a whole new project and copying everything over?
- I'm wondering if I checked the project out incorrectly, but none of the checkout methods (in Subversive) were really applicable: (1) `Check out as a project configured using the New Project Wizard` (why check out as a new project?!?), (2) `Find projects in the children of the selected resource` (no), (3) `Check out as a folder into an existing project` (no).
- Is there any other avenue I could take here to "Java-ify" this project?

Comment: See also [How to change an Eclipse default project into a Java project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179439/how-to-change-an-eclipse-default-project-to-a-java-project)

Comment: The answers below are insufficient to get the project to build and run as normal. See the link by @Pops for a more complete answer. ( e.g. specifying the usage of 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder ' )

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Under `Project Properties -> Project Facets -> Convert to faceted form...` you can select `Java` - this will add the Java functionalities to your project. There you can also add other facets like `Dynamic Web Module` if necessary.

From what you have written the project was checked out correctly. The option `Check out as a project configured using the New Project Wizard` is applicable when the `.project` file does not exist in the repository and you have to select the project type manually. It will only create a new Eclipse project locally.

Comment: I don' see Project Facets on my eclipse

Comment: Note that "Project Facets" is only available in the Java EE version of Eclipse (or with WTP installed). See [Eclipse Bug 102527](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=102527) for having this functionality in all versions.

Comment: I have WTP installed in my eclipse but I can't find the Project Facets option in the properties

Comment: You should probably update this answer to match modern versions of Eclipse.

Comment: @Luís what do you mean? I have just tested it in the current version of Eclipse (4.6) and it still works as I described it.

Comment: Right . Works in the latest 4.7 version exactly as described above.

Answer (score 21):

Partial response: you can convert your project to a Java project by adding the following nature to the `.project` file contained at the root of your project:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
```

And I think that the purpose of the Checkout as New project is to be able to create an "Eclipse project" for a project that has no .project and .classpath file. This allows you, for example, to say that the project is actually a Java project.