# Checking out remote source as a Java project with Eclipse using RSE

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-ec2, remote-debugging, remote-access

I believe I've scanned the web pretty thoroughly and exhaustively on this issue by now, so here goes. I have some source files (Java) that live on a remote machine (Amazon EC2 hosted). I can SSH into the machine, and I can use Eclipse's RSE plugin to view and edit files remotely. Nice!

Now, I want to create a project that would be tied to that remote location. I can do that by selecting a directory in RSE perspective, and selecting (Create Remote Project). That imports the project into Eclipse, and I can view and edit files from there. Nice!

The problem is that this project is imported as a "General" project, while I would like it to be a Java project. There doesn't seem to be a neat way to convert the *remote* project into Java in Eclipse. Is there a way to do that? Note that I'm trying to use tools installed on the remote machine (compilers and such).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with RSE, but you may be able to manually add the java nature / facet to the project metadata. One example is here: [eclipse default project to java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179439/how-to-change-an-eclipse-default-project-to-a-java-project).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export a empty java project into your remote file system. Then use this new project as 'New Remote project'. All other methods that generates a Java.  .project file in the remote folder will work well, too.