# Cannot run as java application in Eclipse, even have correct main() class

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

I get confusing with Eclipse, when I import a project from Git, then I click on a java file, which has correct main function  like:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { }
```

and the outside class has same name with java file. But when I right click the java file, only have "run on server" or "run configuration" option, no "run as java application" like normally. Even if I copy a java file which I can run as java application from different project to this project (no error) then it do not have this option ??? I am quite sure it is nothing to do with the code. I checked the code, totally the same and should be able to run.(I am aware of similar questions on the website but I checked and my problem is not there)

So is there any extra steps I need to do with this project (like maven build ? -> I tried this but also can't run, how to run it properly ?) to have this option again ???

Really confusing !

Comment: can you post the full code so that i can try in my system

Comment: Right click on the project -> properties. In tab 'Resources', what's the type there? Is it project?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a default project type and need to convert it to Java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354109/474189

Comment: resource type is :folder

Comment: The full code is very big project and its not available for sharing. However I know that the file I can right click and choose "run as java app." in another project, copy to this project, now error, but have not that option anymore !

Comment: @Duncan: Thanks but there is no .project file in my computer as in the post of the link mentioned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the project is already imported in your workspace, Right click on your and Configure > Convert to Maven... This will enable the Maven builder and force m2e configurators to setup all the required project natures on your project.

You can also install the m2eclipse-git connector to streamline the "import maven project from git" process. It should be available from Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open Catalog.

Once it's done, you should import your project via Import...> Maven > Checkout Maven Projects from SCM

Comment: I tried all that but it doesn't solve the problem yet. If I run Maven buld, it is not successful, it has some errors.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem! it was very close to your suggestion. Instead of check out by the first option like you said " import your project via Import...> Maven > Checkout Maven Projects from SCM", I choose the 2nd option which is "check out using existing Maven project", then choose the folder I imported using git previously. And now I can run the file from "run as java application". I will choose your question as my answer though. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that projects imported from GIT are not necessarily *java* projects, as Eclipse understands this term. Is the project, as it exists in the repository, an Eclipse project? If it is, it should have two files in its root folder named `.classpath` and `.project`. If these two files are missing, you will need to instruct Eclipse to create them, with logical defaults. Also, if the root folder of the project has a `pom.xml` file, then it is a maven project, which is a whole different kettle of fish.

Comment: Yes, I have pom.xml file. What should I do to use it in Eclipse now ? I used to get project from Git and also have pom file but "after a while" I can run this (I don't remember exactly what step make it have option : run as java application).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue. Below steps solved the problem:

1. Import project from git
2. Right click on Project -> Import -> Import as existing Maven Project
3. One maven module will be imported, you can open .java file with main method from that module
4. Right click, run as -> you can see the option.

Comment: +1, I had a similiar problem for a maven project, I didn't pay close attention to the fact that the project I was dealing with is actually a multi module project.

Answer (score 1):

This can seem obvious but check if the function main is correctly declared. Function's signature must be :

```
static void main (String args[])
```

If you miss this point (ex: you forget scale declaration for args with []) you won't be able to use the option "run as appication", in my case option wasn't displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it might happen when the maven project in not updated on importing to the workspace.

Right click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project..

Then Run As -> Java Application -> Select class containing main method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling multi-module project,
you might be trying to execute the java file( main class) within the parent project itself. That would be the mistake.

Make sure to open the sub- module ( would be listed as separate project in the explorer) and then execute the java file.