# Syntax Checker not working in Git Perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have cloned a repository from github in eclipse.For this I used `EGIT` plugin.
But the syntax checker functionality is not working in the GIT perspective .
I imported the project from `GIT` perspective to `JAVA` perspective also, but same results.

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `.project` of the Eclipse project you just cloned.

If is possible it misses a java nature which would make Eclipse interpret it correctly (especially regarding syntax checking)

See "[How to change an Eclipse default project into a Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179450/6309)": you can modify manually the `.project` and `.classpath` to add the missing elements.