# Can not find or load the main class , why?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have [Git repository](https://github.com/OSryx/Editor) on Github. I clone it using [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) plugin inside Eclipse Mars.

In the *package explorer*, I imported the existing git local repository into a general eclipse project.

I then converted the default project to Java type using this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750958/813853

I set the /src/ folder as Source folder.

When I run as Java Application I get the following error :

```
Error: Can not find or load the main class Editor
```

I don't know from where comes the error ?

### Edit 1

[image]

Comment: And how do you run your application? Is the ["run configuration"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm) correct?

Comment: What exactly do you run as Java Application?

Comment: CTRL+F11 , I don't know how to check if my run configuration is correct, but everything seems legit :s @Tom

Comment: sometime I right-click on the project and choose Run and then Run as aJava Application  @DraganBozanovic

Comment: @OSryx *"but everything seems legit"* So your program works now? :P *"I don't know how to check if my run configuration"* Then read the link I've posted, it might help you.

Comment: no @Tom nothing works ! I am reading your link , I deleted the configuration and start a new run as ... nothing changed

Comment: I have no .class generated ! be careful I updated my question

Comment: Did you build the app? Project -> clean

Comment: on *Project -> Build automatically* is activated. @DraganBozanovic

Comment: Could you try Project -> clean nevertheless?

Comment: it is unclickable, it is in gray !! @DraganBozanovic

Comment: Does `Problems` view report anything?

Comment: nothing :( :( :( @DraganBozanovic

Comment: I downloaded your code from Github and when I right click on the Editor.java file from the project explorer, and run as java application, everything works.

Comment: Please don't add tags to the question title.

Comment: @swingMan did you follow the steps I have done ? or did you proceed in different way ?,

Comment: I didn't do the project conversion like you did. I just created a new Java project in Eclipse and created two new classes with your code.

Comment: I see ... @swingMan if you know another way to import GIT into Java Project. that will be an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `BuildSpec` : I have to do it like this :

[image]

---

I had to modify `.classpath` and `.project` correctly as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179450/813853).

Answer (score 1):

Well, editing the .project and .classpath files is not at all recommended. In your case, you added the java nature but the java builder is not configured and so is not building your project. Instead of importing into a general project and converting it into a java project, you could have created a java project and imported your stuff into it. Just right click the project, choose Import-> File system and choose the src folder in the dialog