# Eclipse doesn't see the project in the run configuration

Tags: eclipse

I want to run a particular class in Ecplise called 'RunCreateNetwork'.

[image]

However, when I choose *Run as* and create new Application Config, it doesn't allow me to choose project, where this class is located.

[image]

Give me an advice how to run it, if you can, please.

Comment: Is this created as a Java project ? I don't see the J in the project icon .

Comment: @Som Bhattacharyya yes it was

Comment: Show us the full folder structure of your project. Also show us the 'Source' tab of the 'Java Build Path' page of the project properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Som noticed correctly, your project doesn't seem to be a Java project (for whatever reason). A Java project would have a 'J' in the upper right corner of the Icon.

Check your project configuration if it has a Java nature. How you do this is alread described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179450/896588).

Comment: Thank you for the link, Andre. I changed .project in a way, that was described there, but it led to big problems. Is there any possibiliy to run my class without doing that?

Comment: @DavidBankom It has to be a Java project. You could backup your work, throw away the project and create a new one where you make sure it's a Java project.