# Eclipse is not showing "Run as Java Application" option. Only shows "Run Configurations"

Tags: java, eclipse

My friend and myself are working on a java assignment and we are using github for version control.
We have a main file which has the correct syntax:
   `public static void main(String args[]) { 
  //code 
}`
Yesterday, I was able to run the main file as a java application. But today my friend made changes to some other files and I updated my repository. Now however I am unable to run the main file even though no changes have been made to it.

What can I do? Even the syntax highlighting is gone.
I am using Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Comment: is the "main file" a class? a method is a part of a class, it can't survive by itself. please post your _main file_.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't think it is a source folder anymore.   Do not share eclipse configuration files in the repository - it is brittle and will break.

Comment: @patateskafa the main file is a java class. I am sorry I cannot post my main file because my university prohibits me from posting assignment code on public forums.

Comment: ah it's ok. check @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen's comment. that's probably the case. for your future questions in SO, consider abstracting, mimicking your code if there's a prohibition of sharing it. that would be helpful for both you and the community.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I see. What should I do? I deleted the repository in eclipse, and imported it again from github, still did not work.

Comment: Convert it into a maven project.  may require elbow grease

Comment: Perhaps this [question+answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179439/how-to-change-an-eclipse-default-project-into-a-java-project) would help

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I converted my java project into a maven project, but it still will not run the main file

Comment: Check whether the project has created as java project or web project.

Comment: Does your class holds `public static void main` ? You won't get `run as java application` in context menu if the class is missing main.

Comment: Show the contents of the panel showing the files in your workspace.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I was able to fix my problem. I imported the github project as an existing eclipse project instead of general project

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up run configurations. Then you must check if you have used `String args[]` in main method parameter. It is necessary in java to add this parameter.
After that you can rerun you class by `run as-> Java application` or `Ctrl + F11`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Follow this.

Right click on your java file and choose "Run As">"Run Configurations".
And add new java application Configurations. See .[image: Imagebelow]
Than, Click on "Run".

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue when I was trying to run a simple program. I had missed the array declaration in the (String arg[] ) . Adding the [] at the end of args solved it.