# Exporting project in eclipse only exporting .classpath and .project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I imported a git folder `https://github.com/TeamLapen/Vampirism.git`  ((If you were wondering)). And so now I have it within my eclipse workspace, but not "really". Here's what I mean: The project shows up in the tree on the left of the eclipse window, but the folder itsself is NOT located in the /workspace/ like the other projects.

All I did in the code was change a few lines to fix a bug, as is highlighted below.
[image]

Anyways, when I go to export the file (File > Export > Jar), a few things happen:
[image]

In the box on the left, you see the project name is "Vampirismx". In the middle box, you see that the project is NOT AVAILABLE FOR EXPORT. In the right box, you see the only files "available" for export are the classpath and project files.

Can someone help me?

**Tl;dr**
I imported an eclipse project from git. When trying to export it, the project isn't showing up.

Comment: You *must* use Gradle to build your mod (you used it to create your workspace), otherwise it won't be reobfuscated and will not work.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the git repository, it does not provide eclipse project settings, and indicates only step by step instructions for intelliJ.

So when you imported it into eclipse, you have it on your workspace like a plain project, not a java one and that is why trying to export it as JAR does not shows up.

You must indicates that the project is a java project and it should work. 
also, i'm not familiar with gradle, but seams there is a goal for settings things in eclipse : https://github.com/TeamLapen/Vampirism#setting-up-vampirism-in-another-environment

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: ok, so try to create manually the missing `.project` and `.classpath` files as described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179439/how-to-change-an-eclipse-default-project-into-a-java-project